# after moving images to sd card..it shows no thumbnail in gallery

Tags: sd-card

I moved the images to SD card using clean master & in gallery it shows no images. It shows NO THUMBNAIL in gallery. Where all these images has moved?

Comment: Thumbnails are probably cached somewhere, so maybe clearing the cache files will help.

Comment: @Huey there's no such setting in the Gallery app. The media-scanner operates independently from that (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short version:

Easy thing: simply reboot.

### TL;DR:

Gallery and many other media apps use a central database to see what images are available. So when you move the files, this database needs to be updated to reflect the changes – which is the responsibility of the [media-scanner](/questions/tagged/media-scanner). Apps specifically designed to deal with media files usually trigger that scanner and tell it to perform a rescan. File managers or tools like your cleanmaster might not do so.

There are multiple other events causing the media-scanner to perform a rescan; for the unexperienced, a reboot is the easiest variant. Alternatives include unmounting/re-mounting the SD card, or use a specific [MediaScanner](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/mediascanner) triggering app.

### PS:

As you've manually moved/re-arranged your media files, also make sure there's no `.nomedia` file in the way (that file tells the media-scanner to *not* index a directory – see [these posts](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[media-scanner]+.nomedia) for details on that topic).